# Snap object pivot to object pivot of target?

Tags: snapping

It's often useful to snap the pivot of one object to the pivot of another. The snap options for snap target are volume, face, vertex etc but no pivot. For the object being snapped centre is available, which in object mode is taken as pivot, but it will snap only to certain objects such as empties. The only way to do this is select the target, use snap pop-up menu to snap cursor to target, select the "snappee", use snap menu again to snap it to cursor. Alternatively use the 'Align Objects' dialogue.
It works but it's tedious, particularly if lots of objects need to be snapped. Surely there's a direct 'select and snap' workflow? If there is I haven't found it.

Comment: I don't think this is possible atm, but a "snap to origin" snapping mode for transform snapping sounds like a useful feature. You might want to try asking the devs if it could be implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the location on both objects to be exactly the same.
What I do is change a pivot's origin on the objects first and then just change their locations to match.
It's not really "snapping" per se, but it aligns then pivots together. You can then parent them, group them, or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the objects that you want to align and have the thing you want to align them to as the active (Cube in this case). In the N menu, Item tab, right click on one of the location values and select 'Copy all to Selected'
[image]

It will copy the cube's location to all the other objects, aligning their locations to the active one

[image]

Then do the same with the rotation value if needed:

[image]

'Copy single to selected' will only align that one axis. This works with Scale as well

There are many ways to align the location, like putting the cursor on the cube and then moving the other objects to it, or scaling to objects to the active cube affecting only Locations, but if you are gonna make the rotation be the same might as well do both in the same menu.